# Is there a way to label an oval (canvas.create_oval) in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, geometry, shapes

I have a `canvas`:

```
window = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(window,
              width=width,
              height=height,
              bg='black')
```

With an `oval`:

```
canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill='red')
```

Is it possible to label this oval as such:

[image]

*Keep in mind the oval in this image has a line coming out which is irrelevant to this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `create_text`:

```
x = abs((x1-x2)/2)
y = abs((y1-y2)/2)
oval_label = canvas.create_text((x, y), text="Label text")
```